# TCL--Regexp matching not happening properly

Tags: regex, syntax, tcl

```
set cell "HEADBUFTIE42D_D3_N"
set postfix "_M7P5TR_C60L08"
set line "  cell(HEADBUFTIE42D_D3_N_M7P5TR_C60L08) { "
if {[regexp "^ +cell[(]$cell$postfix[)] *\\{" $line match]} {
    puts "hello"
}
```

hereI am trying to match the line

```
  cell(HEADBUFTIE42D_D3_N_M7P5TR_C60L08) {
```

*Note that there are 2 spaces in beginning and 1 space after `{`.*

But the match does not happen. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem of not escaping the regexp meta characters properly (`{` is not being escaped, then `[(]` is trying to execute a command named `(`, and so on). It's easier if you use `format` like so:

```
set cell "HEADBUFTIE42D_D3_N"
set postfix "_M7P5TR_C60L08"
set line "  cell(HEADBUFTIE42D_D3_N_M7P5TR_C60L08) { "
set re [format {^ +cell\(%s%s\) *\{} $cell $postfix]
if {[regexp $re $line match]} {
    puts "hello"
}
```

Comment: Care must be taken when assembling a regular expression from pieces. In particular, the pieces injected are regexp fragments, not (necessarily) literals. It's fine in this case as the fragments _are_ matched as RE literals, but it's not generally true; care should be taken…